# How to make sure user input value with RTOS working

Tags: c, task, stm32, uart, freertos

hello i'm new with using RTOS with my board is NUCLEO-G474RE,with my question maybe not clear
well using C# making a GUI to Connect with my board i and sending a value while using RTOS method,
RTOS i have two task there ,Task1 is receive and sendback value that user type also led toggle,
Task2 also is UART receive then flash into my memory,with both task i have send back msg to tell
the task done,the problem is while i send value i cant accuracy flash my value into my board
i have type serval times,i forget to say i only open one uart so i dont think need semaphore
also the GUI i saw the value sendback is right but when i look at the stm32 memory side the value
is ASCII value when i send string is right but sending interger is wrong

fix my question with some pircture sorry i'm new here the picture only show the links

My goal is flash data with uart below is what happen

1.Here is two task ,Task 1 is write the uart receive data into my memory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iOUU.png)

here is my C# gui when i sending data i send back value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66VKa.png)

And while i looking at the memory but the data which write in is wrong
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJFDp.png)

Comment: Hi! Please, improve your question. Please, break it up into paragraphs - one for when you talk about what your system is, what it's supposed to do, another one for how things are configured, and how things break. Also, post your setup and all relevant pieces of code right into the post in text form, not as a picture. It would make your question a lot easier to process and answer!

Comment: Hi sorry that my picture only display in a link,my goal is using rtos doing task and anytime i connect to pc i can write data to the memory

Comment: It seems your HAL UART send is a blocking function. The one where you print "flash done". Also, in a task 2 you have your own uart_write method. So, you're using HAL UART and your own uart function to send data? Clearly, they can't both do it at the same time.

Comment: well hi final i fix this issue with not using hal function,thks for the advices,next time i will  descibe my question clear and more picture

Comment: If you fixed it, post an answer below, describe what you did. Your experience may help someone else or satisfy curious minds like myself.